# How to attach a file in OneDrive to an email?

Tags: vba, outlook, onedrive

I need to send Outlook e-mail with attachments from OneDrive.

The code I used previously isn't working.

```vb
Function Send(Assunto As Range, Corpo As Range, Para As Range)
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OlEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set OlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OlEmail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Folder = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    Nome = "MyFileName"
    
    With OlEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = Corpo & .HTMLBody
        .To = Para
        .Subject = Assunto
        .Attachments.Add Folder & "/" & Nome
        .Save
    End With

End Function
```

I found answers that I need to add the *Type* argument in the `Attachments.Add` method, but it hasn't solved my issue.

Comment: The default location of onedrive is `Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\"`. Try using `Folder = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\THE_REST_OF_YOUR_FILE_PATH"`

Comment: It didn't work. I'm using the company's computer, I couldn't say if they are blocking this action or anything like that. Do you have any more tips @super-symmetry?

Comment: They might have changed the location. The idea is to find the actual path to the location of onedrive. One way to find the path is to open file explorer (shortcut: `WindowsKey`+`E`). Navigate to any folder in your OneDive (say Documents). Click on the navigation bar (where it says `> OneDrive > Documents >`. Now you should see something like `C:\Users\some\path\OneDrive\Documents`

Comment: I did that too. Typing the file path and ````application.path```` method are not working. It is puzzling. I tried to save in a different folder, outside of one drive, and I was unsuccessful too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the attachment type to be 7 and that attaches the file as a link rather than a copy of the online file. For example:

```
OutlookItem.Attachments.Add *WebFilePath*, 7
```

Note, you need to specify a remote URL, not a local file path.